# Where do I save centralized images for Android?

Tags: android

Think of a Pinterest, when someone takes a picture and uploads that picture, where is it saved?  Probably a database (mysql?).  I am trying to do something similar and am not familiar with which options I have.

I understand that SQLite is the central android database, but which DB is most commonly used when being stored external to the phone?  Are there any references out there I could read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps like Pinterest store their data on a central server. The technology they use doesn't have anything to do with Android, and their client software can be an Android or iPhone app, a webpage, etc.

One popular solution (used by services like PhotoBucket, SmugMug, and many others) is [Amazon Web Services (commonly known as AWS)](http://aws.amazon.com/what-is-aws/). In particular, check out their file storage service named S3. You can read about it and how to use it [here](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

One could also use a server that runs a SQL database and some sort of web server to save and retrieve the data. A common solution is [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29), which includes a MySQL server. This approach is more hands-on, but has several drawbacks, including the need to manage the server and ensure its uptime, and also to take care of scaling the service once your user base grows.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Database engines have a type: BLOB (Binary Long OBject) that stores everything exactly  as it is. So you can save an Image, A file( pdf, exe or everything!), ...

To know more about BLOB in sqlite see this: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html